# why can't I split a string and then call each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm confused by this problem. After splitting a string, I try to iterate over it with 'each' but it doesn't work.

```
'hello world foo bar'.split(' ').each(function(word) {
    console.log(word)
})
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work?

Comment: @FelixKling—probably because the OP is confused between jQuery's [*each*](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and ECMAScript's [*forEach*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18) (given the jQuery tag, which I thought to delete but then realised it indicates the confusion).

Comment: [`each`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.each%2F&ei=rVCGVNLHCcn3UNPMgOAP&usg=AFQjCNGWEhQCCVLtjc4aKUDQ621LSgRg_w&sig2=9cCKNwar9cqRTm_OUD_PTg) is a jQuery method. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is the JS native method. You're getting them mixed up.

Comment: I've lost count of the number of times I've written `.each()` when I meant `.forEach()`- it's a daily occurrence. Good job I don't ask a S.O. question every time.

Comment: @Andy Actually, jQuery iterates through an array using [$.each(array, callback)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

Comment: @Mottie, which is why the OP is confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.each()` is a jQuery method and only acts on jQuery collections. For what you're doing you would have to use `$.each( objectOrArray, callback )`

To use jQuery's `$.each()` here is how to do it:

```js
$.each( 'hello world foo bar'.split(' '), function(i,word) {
  console.log( word );
});

/* OUTPUT
hello
world
foo
bar
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**References:**

- [jQuery.each() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)
- [.each() | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Comment: Note that `$.each` is not the same function as `$.fn.each`. Which was the OP expecting? Neither.

Answer (score 4):

Because `each` is not a method of `Array`. Unless you've added such a function to `Array`'s prototype. You might be after [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

```
'a b c'.split(' ').forEach(function (n, i) { console.log(i, n) });
```

Output:

```
0 "a"
1 "b"
2 "c"
```

Comment: You appear to have correct some typos and expanded it, but "each isn't a thing" isn't clear to me.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy—yes, jQuery uses the backward *index*, *value* order (backward compared to ECMA-262).

Comment: @RobG: Sometimes. jQuery gets it right with `$.map` and `$.grep`, but not `$.each` and none of the `$.fn...`versions. I think they must hate their users. ;-)

Comment: @sixfingeredman—yes, and they mess with *this* in the callback also (setting it in some methods, not in others). :-(